# Issue with Json file for Highstock

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I'm actually be doing a project in my studies and i will take `json` data from `webservice` for set it in `highstock`.

My `webservice` (file in php language) return actually this json format

```
[{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"10","minute":"0","p_ac":"143"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"11","minute":"0","p_ac":"827"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"12","minute":"0","p_ac":"965"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"13","minute":"0","p_ac":"1025"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"14","minute":"0","p_ac":"1003"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"15","minute":"0","p_ac":"635"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"16","minute":"0","p_ac":"385"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"17","minute":"0","p_ac":"54"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"18","minute":"0","p_ac":"0"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"19","minute":"0","p_ac":"0"},{"jour":"22","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"20","minute":"0","p_ac":"0"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"9","minute":"0","p_ac":"204"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"10","minute":"0","p_ac":"468"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"11","minute":"0","p_ac":"815"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"12","minute":"0","p_ac":"933"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"13","minute":"0","p_ac":"1062"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"14","minute":"0","p_ac":"332"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"15","minute":"0","p_ac":"536"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"16","minute":"0","p_ac":"348"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"17","minute":"0","p_ac":"73"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"18","minute":"0","p_ac":"0"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"19","minute":"0","p_ac":"0"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"20","minute":"0","p_ac":"0"},{"jour":"23","mois":"1","an":"10","heure":"21","minute":"0","p_ac":"0"}]
```

I need to re-format it for `Highstock`

The correct and complete file for `highstock` :

[Here's the correct code](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?)

How can i do it please ?

Ps : Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please use `code` formatting.

Comment: Where do you want to re-format it? In which language? PHP on backend or JS on frontend? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried nothing because i didn't know if its possible. I need to re-format it in php or js with ajax.

Comment: You can parse your data server-side e.g. using PHP, before exporting to front-end or you could parse your data client-side e.g. using JS, after data is imported to JS. Do you know PHP or JS enough to parse data into defined, expected by Highstock format from data given in your, different format? If not, then you could start from learning basics about PHP or JS e.g. from some online tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. One of my friend do it in php. Problem resolve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [code](http://pastebin.com/3G28m0yp) resolve my problem ! :)